# Resize of NTL vector

Tags: c++, ntl

i would like to resize my ZZ vector during running program. Is there any way, how to make it? I found methods .setLenght() alternatively .DosetLenght(), but  it seems like only initialization step, due to my pro/gram refuses change the vector with these methods..

Many thanks.

```
 Vec<ZZ> v1,v2;
 v1.SetLength(8);
 v2.SetLength(8);
 ZZ velkeCislo,odmocnina,factor,test;
 long i = 0;
 cin >> velkeCislo;
 odmocnina = SqrRoot(velkeCislo);
 cout << "new v1 dlzka " << v1.length() << endl;
 for(i=0;i<v1.length();i++) {
 v1(i) = odmocnina;
 odmocnina++;
 cout << "Number1 " << v1(i) << endl;
 }
 for(i=0;i<v1.length();i++){
   v2(i)=(v1(i)*v1(i))-velkeCislo;
  cout << "Number2 " << v2(i) << endl;
 }
 bool found=false;
 int tp = v1.length();
 cout << "old v1 " << v1.length() << endl;
 v1.SetLength(tp+1); //causes error
  cout << "new v1 " << v1.length() << endl;
```

Comment: This documentation http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/vector.txt disagrees with you. So whatever the problem is, it's not what you think it is. As always on SO, the way to get your problems solved is to **post your code**.

Comment: Well, code was added.

Comment: So, what's the error?

Comment: literally: "cant change this vector's lenght "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is also explained [here](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/vector.txt). You are using the method `v1(i)` to access the array, but this is a 1-based indexing system so you have out of bounds accesses in your program. Replace `v1(i)` with `v1[i]` (which is zero-based) and your program should work.